# Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '', 'article_id': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in developer of django.

I want to create a template tag on homepage of my blog and link to article page of my blog.

Here is my template tag :

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk article_id=photo.article_id %}
```

but cause the error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '', 'article_id': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', 'post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/(?P<article_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

I try (pk and article_id) = 1,2,3 ... and so on.It can function.

Here is my code:

home page html:

```
<div class="story">

    {% for article in article %}

  <div>

    <div>

      <h3><b>{{ article.title }}</b></h3>

      <h5>{{ article.created_at }}</h5>

    </div>


    <div>

      <p>{{ article.content }}</p>

      <div>

        <div>

            <p><button type="button" onclick="location.href='{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk article_id=photo.article_id %}'"><b>READ MORE »</b></button></p>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


    {% endfor %}


</div>
```

view.py:

```
def home(request):

    article = Article.objects.all()
    
    photo = Picture.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'article':article,'photo':photo} )

def post_detail(request,pk,article_id):

    post = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)

    photo = Picture.objects.get(article_id=article_id)

    return render(request,"post.html",{"post":post , "photo":photo})
```

url.py:

```
from blog.views import home,post_detail

path('', home)

path('post/<pk>/<article_id>/', post_detail, name='post_detail')
```

Comment: where is your `post` object coming from on your template?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/<int:article_id>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Walucas commented on your question, you reference a 'post' object in your template that hasn't been passed from your view as context.

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk article_id=photo.article_id %}
                         ^
```

perhaps you mean:

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=article.pk article_id=photo.article_id %}
                          ^
```

easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '', 'article_id': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', 'post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/(?P<article_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

When you read error message, you can understand your mistake.

```
['post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$', 'post/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/(?P<article_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

Meaning of the above output, you should use 'post' keyword instead of 'article'.

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk something=post.something %}
```

I think you should check your other python files.

Your views.py file didn't contain `'views. post_detail'.`

If you make a change like the codes above, I think you can solve your problem.